# Derived categories of curves equivalent then the curves are isomorphic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

I am a beginner at derived categories and I'm looking for a proof of the following fact:

If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective curves such that $D^b(Coh\,X)$ is equivalent to $D^b(Coh\,Y)$ then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

Can anyone give me the explanation of this fact or provide a good reference for this?

As I understand, the crucial point here is that any object in $D^b(Coh \, X)$ splits as a sum of its cohomology sheaves but I don't know how to finish the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: A direct proof using Torelli theorem can be found in [this note](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~mbernard/images/polarization.pdf).

Comment: Crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885106/derived-categories-of-curves-equivalent-then-the-curves-are-isomorphic

Answer (score 7):

The non-elliptic case is easier. By a theorem of Bondal-Orlov, see [Huybrechts, *Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry*, Theorem 4.11]:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties with equivalent derived category $D^b(X)$ and $D^b(Y)$. If the (anti)-canonical bundle of $X$ is ample, then  $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

For elliptic curve, we need a generalized theorem by Kawamata, See [Kawamata, *D-equivalence and K-equivalence*] or [Huybrechts, *Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry*, Theorem 6.15]:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties with equivalent derived category $D^b(X)$ and $D^b(Y)$. Then the (anti)-canonical bundle of $X$ is nef if and only if the (anti)-canonical bundle of $Y$ is nef.

This theorem implies if $X$ is elliptic curve, the so is $Y$.

By [Huybrechts, *Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry*, Theorem 5.39], the hodge structuces of $X$ and $Y$ are the same, which yeilds that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a uniform way to prove it for all curves. For elliptic curves it follows from Hodge theory and for the rest it's a consequence of the Bondal-Orlov theorem. It's all explained in Huybrechts's excellent book on Fourier-Mukai transforms.

Comment: Can you get a uniform proof using Torelli's theorem? It says that if two curves have the same integral Hodge structure (including Poincare duality) then they are isomorphic.

Comment: @WillSawin: that's an interesting thought. I don't know enough of Hodge theory to answer that. I hope someone does though!